# Corrupt JARS in zip using maven

Tags: java, scala, maven, build, jar

I have maven project that i want to package in a zip file including the jar binaries(in a folder /jars). After the packaging, I've unzipped and extracted the jar file but get the below error when i invoke this:

```
PS C:\Users\kenochrome\Downloads> jar xf service-0.1.jar
java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid literal/length code
        at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(InflaterInputStream.java:139)
        at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.read(ZipInputStream.java:142)
        at sun.tools.jar.Main.extractFile(Main.java:715)
        at sun.tools.jar.Main.extract(Main.java:678)
        at sun.tools.jar.Main.run(Main.java:191)
        at sun.tools.jar.Main.main(Main.java:904)
```

Below is a snippet of parent and child poms.

Parent POM

```
    <build>
        <finalName>release_1.0</finalName>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${basedir}/hello/world/00006/jars</directory>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                  <configuration>
                    <descriptor>assembly/bin.xml</descriptor>
                  </configuration>
                  <executions>
                    <execution>
                      <phase>package</phase>
                      <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                      </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Child POM

```
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <nonFilteredFileExtensions>
                        <nonFilteredFileExtension>jar</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                    </nonFilteredFileExtensions>
                </configuration>
                </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>scala-compile</id>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>scala-test-compile</id>
                        <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <finalName>service-${project.version}</finalName>
                    <outputDirectory>../../jars</outputDirectory>
                    <resources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>jars</directory>
                            <filtering>false</filtering>
                        </resource>
                    </resources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I'm sorry if the information is not adequate or if this question is not correctly formatted.

Many thanks for going through this post and much appreciated in advance.

Comment: Check if you released the JAR. I had similar issue when I used some artifactory, which allowed me to upload JAR and even download it from the web interface, but if I tried to download it before pressing the "release" button using the URL from the artifactory, it returned 404 page which was saved as (obviously invalid) JAR. Except it didn't had 404 behavior so I haven't noticed that.

Comment: I know that such errors can occur if your hard disk was full.

Comment: @JF Meier the hard disk is definitely not full but thanks for the comment.

Comment: @Mateusz Kubuszok it’s odd because if i download the jar from artifactory directly and run the “jar xf <jar>” command it’s totally fine but if i extract the jar from the zip file that was built by maven i get the error above. i’m guessing zipping the jar using maven might cause the binary to get corrupted?

Comment: Try to check the size of ZIP and JAR and compare them. It might show some issues.

Comment: @MateuszKubuszok the jar file in the zip package is only slightly less in file size compared to the jar that was uploaded to artifactory directly. there is definitely something up with how maven packages the jars and zipping them. I was told that the <filter> option setting it to false will resolve this by not filtering the binaries during packaging but this does not work or I am setting this incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

Was looking through another forum and found out that the issue that I was having was using the `<lineEnding>unix</lineEnding>` element in my descriptor assembly xml.